# How to clone a subdirectory from a git repo with the directory structure from the repo

Tags: git

I am trying to do a sparse checkout without shallo clone. I am able to do this successfully. But the problem is, when I do, the entire folder structure is being created.

For example:
I am trying to clone the subdirectory at the path:`reponame/path/to/the/directory`
To the local folder: `local_dir`

Now after the sparse checkout, the content of the local_dir is like below:
`local_dir/path/to/the/directory`

But I need the content from the folder `directory` to come directly under `local_dir`. How do I do this?

Side note: I am trying to do this for a golang project. I need to put the golang project inside an already existing repo under a specific directory structure. So if you have any tips on how to do this, please do let me know. I can't put the entire content of the repo inside the go's working dir path.

Comment: If you are interested merely in that one directory (and its contents) you can simply a) clone the repository at the root - or any other place in your filesystem - and then b) move/copy that directory to the golang project structure where you need it.

Comment: I am trying to avoid doing that every time I change the code in that project. Is there anyway I could achieve that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is what SUBMODULES is designed to do.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules